# Input Textbox, Chrome and Firefox

Tags: bug, chrome, firefox

This is possibly the most annoying (albeit not the worst!) thing I've encountered. I've embedded a textbox (input element) in a webpart and it's going about it's business quite nicely.

That was until I tested the application in Firefox and Chrome and realised to my horror that pressing enter in the textbox actually causes the page to go into Edit Mode.

Can somebody verify this? Because it was something that was in Sharepoint 2010, it was reported to be repeatable bug but it's also in 2013 (as I just discovered):
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33df42ba-00b3-41a8-8fb9-f8187cfc216d/strange-behavior-in-firefox-input-text-with-enter-opens-page-for-editing?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Does anybody out there have ideas, since the ones proposed here were for 2010, it didn't work for 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep was actually a good thing (for me).

```
$("#aspnetForm").submit(function (event) {
        return false;
});
```

Comment: as it turns out aspnetForm was the id of the form that resides on every page (the page uses the id and stores it in a variable called theform). Disabling the submission of this form did exactly what I needed it to do.